# Postrgres : overload the inheritance of a group rigths

Tags: postgresql, database-permissions

I would like to know if it's possible under Postgres for a role to inherit the rights of a group while removing the DELETE right from it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, permissions in SQL are always additive, and a role's permissions are the sum of its own privileges and the ones inherited from roles it is a member of.